# How can I check a specific role on triggerer user?(discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot and I created some "commands" for *admin functions* like:

- Restart
- Stop
- Mute, etc...

But when these commands are running, the bot immediately deletes the triggerer message, so that no one can see it.

But I need an another solution, to check, if, the member has a role called "Admin"

But my code, didn't use *ctx* commands, just @on_message and *if* checks...

so I need a code similar to this (and working :D):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == ".admin reset":
        user = message.author
        if "Admin" in user.roles():
            #only for admins
            await message.channel.send("Resetting...")
        else:
            await message.channel.send("You are not an admin")
```

Comment: The real solution is to stop using `@on_message` for basic command processing. The discord.ext.commands extension is extensive and very good. You're just making life hard for yourself and the more you add to the bot in this way the slow you make it and the harder and harder it will be to maintain the spaghetti of `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `user.roles` is a list of `role` objects not names here is what I would do:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == ".admin reset":
        user = message.author
        if "Admin" in [role.name for role in user.roles]:
            await message.channel.send("Resetting...")
        else:
            await message.channel.send("You are not an admin")
```

Just make a list of role names using [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). Also, `user.roles` is an attribute not a method, so parentheses shouldn't be after it.